# BadValueError: Expected list or tuple, got None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to clear out an `ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)` value by setting it to `None` but am getting the error:

> BadValueError: Expected list or tuple, got None

It's pretty straightforward, but the code I'm using is:

```
g.kids_names = None
g.put()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a repeated property.  Try setting it to an empty list: `[]`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that right after posting and it worked. I thought it would insert the empty list into the db, but in the console it does the trick for clearing it out. (I need to wait 11 minutes to accept your answer but will do so.)